# script to kill a process in macos bash not working: illegal process id

Tags: bash, macos, shell, macos-sierra

I created this function to kill a process by partial name, put it in bash_profile, and executed it.
when I run it one command at a time manually, everything works.
but when I call the function, it fails with the output: "illegal process id"

```
function killServer() {
   pid=$(ps -fe | grep '[p]rocessName' | awk '{print $2}')
   if [[ -n $pid ]]; then
      kill $pid
   else
      echo "Does not exist"
   fi
}
```

output:

```
kill: illegal process id: i311821
```

running

```
ps -fe | grep '[p]rocessName'
```

gives:

1543721191 1947 1946 0 9:12AM ?? 0:46.76 ../../jdk/bin/java -server -da -XX:PermSize=256m Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,suspend=n,server=y -DMonitorDisabled -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -Dwrapper.port=32000 -com.XXX.YYY.server.util.Main -b 0.0.0.0 -c default
what is the reason for that?

Comment: Add output of `ps -fe | grep '[p]rocessName'` to your question.

Comment: 1543721191  1947  1946   0  9:12AM ??         0:46.76 ../../jdk/bin/java -server -da -XX:PermSize=256m Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,suspend=n,server=y -DMonitorDisabled -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -Dwrapper.port=32000 -com.XXX.YYY.server.util.Main -b 0.0.0.0 -c default

Comment: Put your last comment in the question

Comment: And you might get more manageable output with something like `ps -cA` instead `ps -fe`

Comment: also `pgrep` might be something to consider

Answer (score -1):

found the problem:
a space after $2 was missing. after the fix, it works:

```
   ps -ef | grep "[X]XX" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2 }' | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: Depending on the process you are trying to kill, you could shorten this significantly using `pgrep`. If there are multiple processes with the same name then you obviously have to do a little more fine tuning.

Comment: That would make zero difference.

Comment: Your error was caused by the *input* to `awk`, not the output. The space isn't necessary, and wouldn't have changed the fact that field 2 contained a non-numeric character (`i`).

Comment: I am nor convinced tge space was the issue. But strangely, things work after adding the space. Without it, awk outputs the first token instead of the second